# How do I run a JavaScript function after adding a new row to a jqGrid control?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid and it is set for in-line editing.

I click the Add New (+) button and it tacks on a new row to the grid and fills the new row with controls for use in filling out data relevant to that new row.

I need to be able to run a bit of JavaScript after the controls show up in the new row that the user will be interacting with to fill in data for the record they are creating.

This is after the Add New button is clicked and after controls get rendered into their respective cells to facilitate the input of data, but before any edits or a save occurs.  This does not have anything to do with pushing or pull data to or from a data source, this is just me trying to work a little client-side magic.

I'm not seeing anything in the jqGrid wiki that lines up with this.  I was thinking there might be some sort of XXXXRendered method, associated with those controls being put on that new line, that I could override, but I'm just not seeing anything.

Any guidance on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you use `inlineNav` for form editing. I would recommend you to use in the case the callback `aftersavefunc` or the event ´jqGridInlineAfterSaveRow´. The first parameter of the callback is `rowid`. If you need to do some actions only after saving *new* row then you can test whether the row has the class `"jqgrid-new-row"`:

```
$("#grid").bind("jqGridInlineAfterSaveRow", function (e, rowid, resp, data, options)) {
    var $tr = $("#" + $.jgrid.jqID(rowid)); // "#" + rowid
    if ($tr.hasClass("jqgrid-new-row")) {
        // do something after a new row is added
    }
});
```